# Bluetooth Low Energy Alert Protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a bluetooth low energy device with a button that, if pressed, should notify another device (tablet). Maybe the tablet is in 'sleep mode' (think of pushing power button on Android device)

What is the best protocol for this use case?

This is an example of what I mean:

- tablet scans for ble devices
- button pressed -> send advertisements
- tablet discovers advertisement of button
- tablet handles this notification (informs the button that the notification was received)
- button goes to sleep
- tablet scans for ble devices

What about the permanent scanning of the tablet? Does this restrict other apps on the tablet? What about the energy consumption?

---

Another protocol might be to have a permanent connection. But to avoid high energy consumption one has to modify connection interval and connection slave latency, which control interval of communication periods and tolerated missing communication periods of the slave device. If the connection is lost it has to be reconnected as soon as possible.

An interesting paper will be: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3478807/?report=reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you devices comply with BLE 4.1, you should have your tablet advertise and initiate connection from button device. You will basically be reversing the topology, but in this scenario you might end up with longer battery life, as the button device only initiates when needed, and your tablet can safely advertise with hundreds of ms intervals.

- Tablet advertises continuously (e.g. every 1 second).
- Button is pressed -> device initiates connection to the tablet, connects in max 1 second, writes data to the tablet's GATT Server, receives confirmation, goes back to sleep.

That's about all.

Comment: I did not get what each device is doing when. Including time constraints. Could you please provide a sequence listing, like in my question? thx

Comment: Yes. Now I got it. Thank you. I'm curious about the downvote it was not by me.

Comment: What a pitty. Currently Android is not able to act as peripheral and send advertisements...

Comment: You are out of luck then in what regards power consumption. I'm not very familiar with Android BLE framework though.

Comment: Peripheral support is meant to be in the L preview but I have not checked personally.  I don't think there will be 4.1 support yet in the OS and what the hardware state is for this is another open question.  Anything were your running all the time even once a second like this will not be good at all for the battery.

Comment: @Ifor The solution I presented is best from a power consumption perspective. The main goal is to limit the power consumption on the "peripheral" (i.e. smaller device), and in this specific scenario the OP wants, turning the peripheral into central reduces its activity to the absolute minimum. If you are not happy with the tablet advertising once per second, then imagine another scenario. But the OP has presented a scenario and that's the solution for it.